# Creation of users and Assigning policies to them in Hyperledger

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I have a 2 channels running on my Hyperledger Blockchain I need to create users and need to create a policies for them to access the particular channels how do I do it.  I have fabric-ca server running what do I do next

Answer (score 0):

Users need to establish identity by getting a certificate signed by one of the CA (certificate authority) certs that are in the channel configuration block. Channel configuration block contains MSP (membership service provider) information of each organization participating in the channel. MSP info includes that CA certificate. Any user participating in the channel must have a certificate signed/issued by the CA certificate.

If an organization is using Fabric CA server as the certificate authority, then it can be used to register, enroll users. Enrolling users will get them a certificate. Then a user with channel writer authority can add the user's certificate to the channel config block to give him/her either reader or writer authority.

Comment: how to add user's certificate to channel config block

Comment: You do it when you create the channel, i.e. when you create the channel you define the members of it and you define where their certificates are located. You have to change the configtx.yaml file. You have more info about it in the Hyperledger Fabirc documentation: http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html#run-the-tools